# React throws undefined error for an existing element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, foreach

I'm trying to walk through an array and use its data but it was returning the error:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**

This is the result of the log:

```
class Restockers extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       ...
    }
  }

  render() {
    const rows = [];
    console.log('props: ', this.props); // this logs the content of props
    this.props.restockers.restockers.forEach(...)

  }
}
```

So when there is `this.props.restockers.restockers` in the code, in the log it is only `this.props.restockers`, which has an empty array.

Like in the next screenshot:

[image]

So I remove that extra `restockers` from the code. And now look at my error and my log:

[image]

I don't understand this weird behavior, now in the log it is `this.props.restockers.restockers` so the code is wrong because it is `this.props.restokers`.

How can this be solved?

Comment: Don't trust the console. It changes the shape of your array to make it easier to read and can be updated when the displayued data changes during runtime. Please show us how your props is loaded, how do you get your data ?

Comment: have you tired using ```map```?

Comment: Print `this.props.restockers` and not `this.props`. In both consoles outputs there's an object `restockers` with a `restockers` array. So `this.props.restockers.restockers` does get you an array. It just looks like you create a `restockers` object initially and load up the `restockers` key asynchronously.

Comment: It would be helpful to show in your question the implementation of `Restockers`'s parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an array of element to jsx. The problem is that forEach does not return anything (i.e it returns undefined). So better use map because it returns an array like this.

```
render() {
    const rows = [];
    console.log('props: ', this.props); // this logs the content of props
    this.props.restockers.restockers.map((restocker, i) => {     
           console.log("Entered");                 
           // Return the element. Also pass key     
           return (<Restockerkey={i} restocker={restocker} />) 
        })

  }
```